# Can't manage to create a simple regex pattern

Tags: php, regex

I need to check if this string exists in a string:

```
[INFO Client 169244] @RandomName: random message
```

I never really understood how RegEx patterns work and even after reading some tutorials, I can't figure out the pattern. I tried this, but it looks like it's totally wrong.

```
$pattern = "/[\INFO Client [0-9]]\ @[a-zA-Z]: (.*)/";
```

Any help with an explanation would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what you want:

`/\[INFO Client \d*\] @[a-zA-Z]*: (.*)/`

and the first captured group `\1` will be `'random message'`.

Demo: http://regex101.com/r/iI6nM4

Answer (score 0):

You should escape `[` and `]` by `\[` and `\]` and not what you are doing.

```
/\[INFO Client \d*\] @[a-zA-Z]+?: (.+)/
```

The First Group will contain `random number`